# How to add a scrollbar for a Boxee RSS App?

Tags: scrollbar, boxee

I have a Boxee.tv RSS App with a grid display of the videos and vertical scrolling possibility.
How to add a visible scrollbar?

Regards,
Pentium10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the scrollbar control

```
<control type="scrollbar" id="60">
        <visible>false</visible>
        <posx>65</posx>
        <posy>703</posy>
        <width>1130</width>
        <height>10</height>
        <textureslidernib>fora_search.png</textureslidernib>
        <textureslidernibfocus>fora_search.png</textureslidernibfocus>
        <texturesliderbackground>fora_dark_bg.png</texturesliderbackground>
        <orientation>horizontal</orientation>
        <showonepage>false</showonepage>
    </control>
```

Comment: Where did you find the names `fora_search`, `fora_dark_bg` etc?

Comment: @Jesse Dhillon From the Fora.TV application source.